# Calling an Assembly x86 function from C: Taking in a dynamically allocated parameter

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I am writing am Assembly program that will be compiled into a standard library for the following C function signature:

```
int isMatrixElementValue(int r, int c, int** matrix, int targetValue)
```

I know how to get the first two parameters (`r` and `c`):

```
EBP = return address
EBP + 4 = return value
EBP + 8 = r
EBP + 12 = c
EBP + 16 = matrix
```

However, I don't know how to get the `matrix` parameter. I know where it's start memory address is, but since `matrix` is dynamically allocated, I don't know how many bytes it could be. Furthermore, I don't know how to get the `c` parameter if I don't know how many bytes the `matrix` parameter occupies.

Comment: matrix is a pointer (actually a pointer to a pointer or a pointer to an array of pointers) so it is 4 bytes.

Comment: Your stack layout is confused.  In the usual manner of setting up a stack frame, the value at stack address EBP is the saved EBP from the caller, and EBP+4 is the return address.  As I said in another answer, return values go in EAX.  But Michael is right that what's at EBP+16 is merely a pointer, not the entire array - C never passes arrays by value.  Then `targetValue` is at EBP+20 as you'd expect.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you so much for the answer. Appreciate the help and got it fixed :D.

Comment: @AdamLee: Glad to hear it.  You could post an answer and accept it, to make it clear that the question is resolved.